# Parse for a specific value in nested json using php

Tags: php, json

I know this question has been asked, but i'm at my wit's end and cannot figure this out.

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "url": "http://whatever",
        "name": "whatever"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://anything",
        "name": "anything"
    }
] }
```

In my PHP file, I have this:

```
    // Read JSON file
$json = require('blogtest.json');

//Decode JSON
$arr = json_decode($json,true);

// Loop through Object

if (is_array($arr) || is_object($arr))
{
    foreach ($ar as $arr)
    {
        echo $ar["objects"]["name"] + "<br>";
    }
}
```

and instead of printing the name values - it prints the entire json file. I've tried changing the filters, writing it different ways, and I just cannot get json to ever do what I need.

Is there any possible way to just get this to print out the two "name" values?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `require` with `file_get_contents`.
What `require` does is to include the file, not to return the contents of the file.

Then you can loop the items with

```
foreach($ar["objects"] as $item) {
    // $item['name'];
}
```

Comment: I did that originally, if I use file_get_contents it tells me the file does not exist

Comment: Then that's the error that you want to solve. What's the absolute path of `blogtest.json`, and the absolute path of your php file?

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop is wrong.

The `foreach` block should be written as:

```
foreach ($arr['objects'] as $ar) {
    echo $ar["name"] . '<br />';
}
```

Also, use `file_get_contents` instead of `require`.

Comment: this errors out with "invalid argument supplied for "foreach()"